# PHP getting "Permission denied" while allow_url_fopen is on

Tags: php, file, file-permissions

I'm going to load an image from a single url by php. I use this `file_put_contents`:

```
$url = 'http://www.example.com/test.jpg';
$img = 'C:\xampp\htdocs\myproject\assets';
file_put_contents($img, file_get_contents($url));
```

Also in my `php.ini` I have this:

```
allow_url_fopen=On
```

**But I get this error:**

```
Severity: Warning

Message: file_put_contents(C:\xampp\htdocs\trendkala\fereydoon\assets): failed to open stream: Permission denied

Filename: controllers/admin.php

Line Number: 55

Backtrace:

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\trendkala\fereydoon\application\controllers\admin.php
Line: 55
Function: file_put_contents
```

Comment: change `$img = 'C:\xampp\htdocs\myproject\assets';` to `$img = 'C:\xampp\htdocs\myproject\assets\test.jpg';`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the problem is with your file path where you are writing the contents. You need to add the file name in the file path which makes it a fully qualified path.

Something like:

`$img = 'C:\xampp\htdocs\myproject\assets\test.png';`

Also make sure you have write permission for the folder.